View Immersive option is not visible on the AVPlayer
I'm trying to build a player to view spatial videos. When I try to open the video normally from Files or Photos in my VisionPro simulator, the View Immersive option is showing and the spatial video is representable. But I cannot view the same option in the player I build using AVPlayer

Here's my ContentView
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ImmersiveVideoViewModel
    @Environment(\.openImmersiveSpace) var openImmersiveSpace
    @Environment(\.dismissImmersiveSpace) var dismissImmersiveSpace
    @State private var showVideoPlayer = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(viewModel.showImmersiveSpace ? "Back to Reality" : "Show Immersive space", isOn: $viewModel.showImmersiveSpace)
                .toggleStyle(.button)
                .onChange(of: viewModel.showImmersiveSpace) { _, newValue in
                    Task {
                        if newValue {
                            if viewModel.videoType == .degree180 {
                                showVideoPlayer = true
                            } else {
                                await openImmersiveSpace(id: "VideoImmersiveView")
                            }
                        } else {
                            await dismissImmersiveSpace()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .controlSize(.extraLarge)
            
            Picker("Video Type", selection: $viewModel.videoType) {
                Text("360°").tag(VideoType.degree360)
                Text("180°").tag(VideoType.degree180)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showVideoPlayer) {
            if let playerViewController = viewModel.presentVideoPlayer() {
                VideoPlayerViewControllerRepresentable(playerViewController: playerViewController)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        return playerViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {}
}

Here's my ImmersiveViewModel:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import AVKit

enum VideoType {
    case degree360
    case degree180
}

class ImmersiveVideoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showImmersiveSpace = false
    @Published var videoType: VideoType = .degree360
    
    func generateVideoMaterial(for type: VideoType) -> VideoMaterial? {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SPATIAL", withExtension: "mov") else {
            print("Error loading video")
            return nil
        }
        
        self.videoType = type
        
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let videoMaterial = VideoMaterial(avPlayer: avPlayer)
        avPlayer.play()
        
        return videoMaterial
    }
    
    func presentVideoPlayer() -> AVPlayerViewController? {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SPATIAL", withExtension: "mov") else {
            print("Error loading video")
            return nil
        }
        
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = avPlayer
        
        avPlayer.play()
        
        return playerViewController
    }
}

Here's the result of the code:


Note: The video opened using Files is the same as the video that I loaded on my code!


AVPlayer isn’t a View it doesn’t have any Buttons. The controller has buttons. But the immersive button is something else we don’t have access too.

Any idea how to achieve the same effect on the native player from photos/files programmatically? Appreciate your reply, thank you!

On the native player, I don't think it is possible. You have to take a portion of the image and blur it and move the position of the player.

Okay, thank you. Is there a way to programmatically play a 180-degree spatial video? Is it similar to playing a 180d video on YouTube? I tried to do for 360 degree video by spreading the video on a sphere and it works. Just wondering if there's any way for 180degree videos

You have to create a procedural mesh of a half sphere or bring in a 3D model of a half sphere
